# Eclipse MarketPlace not woking

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy

When i try to install new software using Eclispe Market place, I always getting the below error.
The version of eclispe I am using is **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2**

```
        MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
  Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/featured/api/p?product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&os=win32&java.version=1.8.0_05&client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&product.version=1.4.2.20120131-1457&runtime.version=3.7.0.v20110110&ws=win32&nl=en_US.
```

Read timed out

I know this problem occurs because of the proxy setting.

When I searched in google and found that we need to set proxy settings in Pereference --> General --> Internet Connection.

[image]

Even I tried the other way by setting proxy information in eclipse.ini file

```
    -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
   -Dhttp.proxyPort=****
   -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.****.com
   -Dhttp.proxyUser=******
   -Dhttp.proxyPassword=******
```

-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1

Can I know where I have made a mistake in making the porxy setting in eclispe.
Can any one help me please.

Comment: I think you need to define https proxy, too. If you dont have one use the same as http.

Comment: @Stefan Still the same after proxy setting for https as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the proxies to manual **AND**  set it before **AND** after `-vmargs` in your `eclipse.ini`

```
   -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
   -Dhttp.proxyPort=****
   -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.****.com
   -Dhttp.proxyUser=******
   -Dhttp.proxyPassword=******
   -vmargs
   -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
   -Dhttp.proxyPort=****
   -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.****.com
   -Dhttp.proxyUser=******
   -Dhttp.proxyPassword=******
```